# Django key violates unique constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a strange issue where the same PK is being generated giving me the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Comment_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(uxlt72XrRu-fm260qHo9Zg) already exists.
```

This is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=28, unique=True,
                          default="make_id()", editable=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

Function to generate ID:

```
def make_id():
    return base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).decode("utf-8")
```

How I get the error:

> c = Comment.objects.create(description="test") < ==== works
>
> c2 = Comment.objects.create(description="test2") < === violates unique constraint

So why is my model not generating a new ID each time? The same thing happens in tests not just shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct usage of the default param is: `default=make_id`. So, the field line would be:

```
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=28, unique=True,
                      default=make_id, editable=False)
```

Comment: Migrations might not work, but why would you want a lambda in the first place if you can just pass the function?

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default